# set the result of a generator function in a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In C# I can call method `.ToList()` to get all results from a iterable function, like this:

```
var results = IterableFunction().ToList();
```

Following the code below, how can I set the result in a variable?

```
function* gen() { 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

var results = ???;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this works:

```
function* gen() { 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

var results = [...gen()];
```

I came up with this by fiddling around with [this example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#User-defined_iterables).

For information about the spread operator (`...`), have a look at [this documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Be aware of its [current limited browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Browser_compatibility) support, though.

Comment: Very good, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the spread operator would be just to use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which takes any iterable source and creates an array from it:

```
function* gen() { 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
var result = Array.from(gen());
```

Answer (score 1):

Step by step

```
function* gen() { 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

var g = gen();
var results = [];
results.push(g.next().value);
results.push(g.next().value);
results.push(g.next().value);
console.log(results);
```

Alternatively, using a `for` loop

```
function* gen() { 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

var results = [];

for (var g = gen(), curr = g.next(); !curr.done
  ; results.push(curr.value), curr = g.next());

console.log(results);
```

another approach would be to use `for..of` loop

```
function* gen() { 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

var results = [];

for (let prop of gen()) {
  results.push(prop)
}

console.log(results)
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this haha

Answer (score 0):

A helper function:

```
function generator_to_list(generator) {
    var result = [];
    var next = generator.next();
    while (!next.done) {
        result.push(next.value);
        next = generator.next();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then your code:

```
function* gen() { 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
var result = generator_to_list(gen());
```